# Tag variables as being accessible on runtime

Tags: c++, console

I have learned to code in c# and now that I am using c++ for a specific project I am clueless about hwo this can be done in c++ :

Basically in c# you can do something like this :

```
[XmlElement("RootNode")]
public string name {get;set;}
```

this will map the variable to a xml tag when serializing. You can also code your own tags and design their behaviors.

What I am trying to do is a developper console for an application. I would like to be able to do something similar say :

```
[ConsoleAccessible("ConsoleName")]
```

and this would cause the variable to be accessible by the console. then in the developper console you could change the value of the variable during runtime.

Is there a way in C++ to "tag" a variable and associate a certain behavior to it?

Comment: Maybe there's a specific mechanism supporting this for c++-cli. In standard c++, there's no such thing.

Comment: These are called annotations, generally. In C++, we have [attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), but if you want to use your own custom attributes, you will need to develop a compiler extension. However, I'm sure it would be easier to just create a `registerConsoleVariable` where you give it a name and a reference to an object and it makes it accessible to the developer console you're creating.

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield Yea I tought about that. Just thought that it would be a cleaner way to do it with annotations rather then having a bunch of calls in the constructors and then having to search throught the calls to find a variable when you want to change something. Is creating a custom attribute (compiler extension) portable ? I mean if someone pulls the project does it runs or will he have to install my extension first?